# Dockerizing multi-node python django backend served by nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize a project that consists of multiple backend nodes that are served by a nginx server. Would I rather have an instance of nginx running in each docker container serving just that node or would I have a "central" NGINX server that serves all nodes.

In case of having a central nginx server, how would it communicate with the backend nodes.

The backend is implemented in python django. If each container has its own nginx instance, the communication between the web server and the python django application is straightforward. But how would I serve a python django application that lives in one container from a nginx server that lives in another?

In case of having an instance of nginx in each container, how would that impact the overall performace of the system?